# Why are my line-endings still wrong according to CodeSniffer?

Tags: coding-style, phpstorm, line-endings

I made a git hook that checks my code style before commit. It passes the staged files to CodeSniffer. I use the PSR-2 code style which means newlines should be `\n` even on Windows. However even after changing PhpStorm settings and git settings it still gives me the error that the newlines are `\r\n`. Why does this happen?

**PhpStorm**
Searching for `\r\n` with regex on does not return instances, so I believe the problem to lie with git.

[image]

**.gitconfig**

```
[core]
    autocrlf = false
    editor = \"C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitExtensions.exe\" fileeditor
    eol = lf
[user]
    name = Thomas Moors
    email = thomas.moors@*****.nl
[merge]
    tool = kdiff3
[mergetool "kdiff3"]
    path = C:/Program Files (x86)/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
[diff]
    guitool = kdiff3
[difftool "kdiff3"]
    path = C:/Program Files (x86)/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
```

**The error**

[image]

Transcription:

```
FILE: ...\Thomas\Documents\example-live\laravel\app\Models\DoMdokUser.php
----------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 1 ERROR AFFECTING 1 LINE
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | ERROR | [x] End of line character is invalid; expected "\n" but
   |       |     found "\r\n"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
PHPCBF CAN FIX THE 1 MARKED SNIFF VIOLATIONS AUTOMATICALLY
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Time: 105ms; Memory: 4Mb

Fix the error before commit please
```

**edit:** using another editor (n++) the problem **does** seem to lie with phpstorm. Replacing \r\n fixes the problem. So why does PHPStorm not work properly?

Comment: This works for me, but only when the file is saved. Make sure to change something in the file!

Comment: @Aine It's already fixed :) lazyone helped

Comment: I figured so, since you asked it two years ago! :) I ran into this issue today, and just added the comment, as it might help someone else in future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Searching for `\r\n` with regex on does not return instances, so I believe the problem to lie with git.

Not necessarily with git.

IDE (PhpStorm) stores all lines in memory with normalized line separator (which is `\n` / `LF`) and when you saving the file it replaces them with actual line separator symbol detected on file opening. This also means that if you happen to have mixed line endings in one file (e.g. both `CRLF` and `LF`) .. after save it will use only one style (e.g. only `LF`).

Normalized line ending allows you to execute your regex searches/replaces in a bit more simpler way -- no need to worry about what the actual symbol is.

---

Now -- the `Code Style` settings page -- as you can see in that hint below the field, it says: "Applied to new files". This means that this setting does NOT affect existing files in any way.

**To change line ending for a particular existing file:** open the file and either change it via appropriate section in Status Bar .. or via `File | Line Separators`

[image]

[image]

---

> So why does PhpStorm not work properly?

It works properly -- you just happen to not know how to change the line separator style.

Comment: I am also using PHPStorm and changed Line Separaters of some files, but from time to time they change back to CRLF.  I don't know what is the exact reason but it is really problem for me, because my unit tests are failing because of it.