# Carriage Return not recognized by SplFileObject

Tags: php, symfony, csv, phpstorm

I am trying to build a service called `DataFileParser` in my Symfony application which reads a csv file. I changed the `parse` function of my service for the purpose of this question, to make it look more simple: in my code snippets, my function just loops through the lines of the csv file and dumps them.

My `DataFileParser` looks like this:

```
class DataFileParser
{
    /**
     * @param string $filename
     * @param array $expectedColumns
     *
     * @return EntryIterator
     */
    public function parse($filename, $requiredColumns, $expectedColumns)
    {
        $splFileObject = new \SplFileObject($filename, 'r');

        $splFileObject->setFlags(\SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
        $splFileObject->setCsvControl(';');

        foreach ($splFileObject as $line) {
            var_dump($line);
        }

        die;
    }
}
```

My csv file looks like this:

```
firstname;lastname;mail
john;small;jonh.small@fakemail.com
```

My parse function output looks like this:

```
array(5) {
    [0]=> string(9) "firstname"
    [1]=> string(8) "lastname"
    [2]=> string(9) "mail john"
    [3]=> string(5) "small"
    [4]=> string(23) "jonh.small@fakemail.com"
}
```

As you can see on the index #2, the SplFileObject does not detect the end of line between the last header "mail" and the "john" string, as it prints `[2]=> string(9) "mail john"` whereas I would have expected the following

```
[2]=> string(4) "mail"
[2]=> string(4) "john"
```

If I use the dump function of the `var_dumper` component of Symfony instead of `var_dump`, I get this

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => "firstname"
  1 => "lastname"
  2 => "mail\rjohn"
  3 => "small"
  4 => "jonh.small@fakemail.com"
]
```

As you can see, the SplFileObject does not detect the `\r` as the end of the first line.

If I manually set the PHP parameter `'auto_detect_line_endings'` to true by calling `ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',true);` before the SplFileObject constructor, then it works fine and I get the following output (correct one) with the dump function.

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "firstname"
  1 => "lastname"
  2 => "mail"
]

array:3 [▼
  0 => "john"
  1 => "small"
  2 => "jonh.small@fakemail.com"
]
```

Last details, the `$filename` parameter of my parse function is an instance of the class `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile`. My operating system is Mac OS X El Capitan, I am using MAMP with PHP version 7.1.8 and I am using PhpStorm to edit the CSV file (I checked my PhpStorm config for coding style and have already set `\n` as the line separator).

#### Now my question is:

How can I set the SPLFileObject to detect the `\r` as a line break without having to change the PHP variable `auto_detect_line_endings`? As well as detecting all types of line breaks (`\r`, `\n`, `\n\r`) through all operating systems as line breaks?

(P.S.: Maybe it is an issue with my PhpStorm editor since I cannot figure out how to insert a `\n` with the enter key. So if anybody knows why my PhpStorm does not insert `\n` instead `\r` even though I have defined `\n` as the line separator, I would be glad to share knowledge).

Screenshot of PHPStorm Configuration of Line break:

[image]

Comment: instead of set a flag you could do it line per line : https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/splfileobject.fgetcsv.php

Comment: 1) *"I checked my PhpStorm config for coding style and have already set \n as the line separator"* Where? Screenshot please. 2) Have you created this file in PhpStorm .. or was it some existing file/created elsewhere? 3) I'm asking because the option that you have used (at least I'm thinking so) affects only newly created files inside IDE. For existing files you need to change line ending manually on per file basis (e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21281924/783119 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/48423157/783119). This means -- your file already uses `\r` so IDE just preserves it.

Comment: Thank you @LazyOne for your reply. You were right, actually I generated the csv with the export of an .xml file to .csv file with Microsoft Excel, which put "\r" instead of line breaks. So PHPStorm preserved it.

Changing the File > Line Separators fixed the problem.

I also added a screenshot for the purpose of the community coming through my question.

Comment: @MacBooc I appreciate your help and thank you. Unfortunately, the solution you provided did not work.